# populate a spreadsheet column with index()?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm creating a new table by using data from another one, where I want to avoid copying the formulas in the first row down to all rows.

In col2 I used the index() function in the first data row, to populate the rest of col2.
I would like to do something similar in col3, but I need to use an if statement, something like:

```
=if(index(A2:A)="x"; true; false)
```

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: can you please clarify your question? show example of  your end goal?

Comment: It is not possible (in my version of excel), because `index(A2:A)` is not correct, it has a syntax error.

Comment: @look sorry meant google-spreadsheets, corrected the tag

Comment: @amitklein col3 has the desired result, but should produced by a formula in c2

Comment: why use a formula in col2 to get results in c3? Do you want col2 to be the formula that col3 is cheking?

Comment: Formula in B2 creates the data in B3 to B5. I want similar for C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `index()`, you can just use `ARRAYFORMULA` instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A);"";IF(A2:A="x";TRUE;FALSE)))
```

[image]

Since the whole column is referenced, you need to consider blank values below A5. Thus `ISBLANK()` is used to check and "populate" the blank rows.

**Reference:**

[ARRAYFORMULA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

[ISBLANK()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en)